# AJAX Editing in list view for symfony 1.4

Tags: php, jquery, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm looking for a way to edit rows within a list view of the Symfony 1.4 admin-generator backend CRUD interface.

Rather than clicking edit and going through to an edit form, then having to click save and returning to the list view, I'd like to be able to edit the column entries for each row within the list view itself.

I used to have an article on this, I believe it may have been some German or Dutch engineers who were looking into it, but lost it forever after my speed dial crashed.

While I'm aware of how one would do it in principal, does any one know of any resources or have any practical technical advice on how to do this (if it is at all feasible in the first place)?

Comment: You have a look at Google and maybe [found this article](http://davedash.com/2006/08/13/digg-style-ajax-comment-editing-in-phpsymfony/).

Comment: For the benefit of j0k and all other newcomers, I've been looking through google for 3 days and I've tried numerous keyword combinations but to no avail..

Comment: That article looks interesting, thank you J0k, but it's more geared toward comment editing rather than the admin-generated list view.. Of course that isn't to say I couldn't extrapolate from there but I'm on tight deadlines and would like to find something more "on target" as it were..

Comment: First lesson learned so far: I should backup my speed dial! :(